# Firebase push mutiple objects with keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im not sure how it calls, But I just want to push data like :

By using `.push()`

```
{
    '{this_should_be_a_key}' : {
        name : '',
        items : {
            '{this_should_be_a_key}' : {
                title : ''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Now I do something like :** should be good with **promise**

```
ref.push({
    'name' : ''
}).then(function(snapshot) {
    let key = snapshot.key;
    ref.child(key+'/items').push({
        title : ''
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This **I have to push 2 times**, Any easier way to do or **its possible to push just one time** ? Like..

```
ref.push({
    'name' : '',
    'items' : {
        '{this_should_be_a_key}' {
            'title' : ''
        }
    }
}).then(function(snapshot) {
    alert('done');
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's push keys are actually generated on the client and you can generate one by calling `push` with no arguments. It will return a `Reference` and its `key` will be the generated push key. This is entirely client-side and does not involve communicating with the server.

So you can generate a key, prepare your data and then call `push` again:

```js
var key = ref.push().key;
var data = {
  name: '',
  items: {}
};
data.items[key] = { title: '' };

ref.push(data)
  .then(function () { console.log('pushed'); });
  .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: Yep, pretty much: https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11

Answer (score 0):

you can make a separate node for the `items` list and just save the key at the parent element